# select two tables from mysql with bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables with the same id. How I can take two tables from the same string. I have tried this but doesn't work. I need it to use the data from both tables on the same page
I have tried also this `$sql = "SELECT vm_users.*, vm_menu.*  FROM vm_users , vm_menu WHERE id = ? ";`

```
$id = $decoded["id"];
$id_user_type = $decoded["id_user_type"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vm_users, vm_menu WHERE id = ? ";           
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");     
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param('i', $id );
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

now I have this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in /web/htdocs/home/view/top_pannello_personale.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /web/htdocs/home/gestione_menu.php(1): require() #1 {main} thrown in /web/home/view/top_pannello_personale.php on line 18

Comment: What is the error? [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: You have to specify which table the id is to come from, for example, `WHERE vm_users.id = ?`

Comment: the error now is: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a join e.g.:

```sql
SELECT vm_users.* , vm_menu.*
FROM vm_users
INNER JOIN  vm_menu WHERE vm_users.id = vm_menu.id 
AND vm_menu.id = ?
```

Based on your schema you should adapt the proper join condition  vm_users.idmenu = vm_menu.id

Comment: `id = ?` is ambiguous, which table's id will count, assuming both have an `id` column.

Comment: What makes you think that @Dharman? the OP has not ever shown us the schema.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The error they have posted in the comments. :D